# mutate-join between a vector and a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering if there is a method analogous to dplyr mutating joins for joining a vector and a data-frame instead of two data-frames. Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is to transform values in a vector based on key-pairs in a data frame. The approach I came up with so far is this:

```
vec <- c("hi", "hey", "hello")
df <- data.frame(
  start = c("hi", "hello", "hey", "hallo"),
  end = c("bye", "see ya", "adieu", "see you later alligator"))

data.frame(bla = vec) %>% 
  left_join(df, by =c("bla"="start")) %>% 
  magrittr::use_series("end")
```

returns correctly

```
[1] "bye"  "adieu"  "see ya"
```

This approach works but it seems silly to have to create a new data-frame based on `vec`. I would prefer to use the vector directly. Note that simply filtering `df` based on `vec` is not sufficient as that would not preserve the same order of values.

```
filter(df, start %in% vec) %>% 
  magrittr::use_series("end")
```

returns incorrectly

```
[1] "bye" "see ya" "adieu"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tibble::deframe` will turn your data frame into a named vector that you can use to look up values from `vec`:

```r
tibble::deframe(df)[vec]
```

From the documentation `?deframe`

> converts two-column data frames to a named vector or list, using the first column as name and the second column as value

---

In base R this would look like:

```r
setNames(df$end, df$start)[vec]
```

Note: If you want an unnamed vector as your output just wrap either answer in `unname()`

Or you can just match the values and use those indices to get the new value:

```r
df$end[match(vec, df$start)]
```